# Term for the mean of the minimum and maximum of a set of real numbers

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory, terminology, average

I've been programming something for a few days now, and there's a concept I find myself lacking a name for that I feel like I should know offhand.

**Is there a term (generally accepted or otherwise) for the halfway point between the minimum and maximum value of a set of reals?**

In other words, a term for the centroid of the smallest line encompassing all members of the set?

For explicitness's sake, I mean the term for the value given by
$$\frac{\max(S) + \min(S)}{2}$$

where $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

I suppose higher-dimensional analogues exist, like if you found the centroid of the smallest-possible $n$-ball all points lived in— I would be happy with either a term for this general phenomenon or a narrower term for just real numbers/1D points.

Comment: Centre of mass maybe? Also, I think your formula should be $\frac{\max(S) + \min (S)} 2$

Comment: 'Midpoint' seems appropriate since this is one dimensional, though maybe it slightly implies it's actually contained in the set itself which may or may not be desired.

Comment: Yeah in hindsight centre of mass is incorrect for most sets but if $S$ connected it’s alright

Comment: In statistics this is called the midrange.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-range.

Comment: @JackT updated! And yeah, specifically mean/centroid/center of mass fail for my use-case.

Comment: @paw88789 midrange is a pretty good short-term option, as it seems unambiguous on lookup. Will probably use that unless someone finds something that has more general currency